# Why my iPhone's LAN address is different with the arp -a address?

Tags: ethernet, iphone

In my house, I use:

`arp -a`

to show the LAN addresses, and I find there is two connect, one is my Mac:`a0:99:9b:17:50:7`, and the other should be my iPhone's.

[image]

But I see my iPhone's Lan address is: `BC:A9:20:35:F9:68`, but the address in `arp -a` show is `d4:5f:25:e5:f0:bd`.

[image]

Why there is difference ?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 with the d4:5f:25:... MAC address is most likely your router, not your phone.

Comment: @brhans agreed, and manufacturer is *Shenzhen YOUHUA Technology Co., Ltd*.

Comment: i did not find my iphone addr on the arp-a list

Comment: Why do you want to find it there? You have issues with connectivity? Ask question about your real problem. Probably your iPhone is simply was not connected to the device you perform ARP on, and the device does not have it on the list in its ARP cache.

Comment: verify and disabuse. and at least i can find if some other peaple are using my net

Comment: Migrated to wrong site. It should be on netwrok engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> verify and disabuse. and at least i can find if some other peaple are using my net

Prevent abuse: if you want MAC-level security, you can allow specific MAC addresses using your router connection, and disallow all other devices; but you should know that

- MAC addresses can be spoofed (but for this cracker needs to know your router settings);
- router is usually required to connect to the outer world (internet), setting its security will not prevent others connecting to some *other* device on the network (e.g. your MacBook).

Verify who is connected: ARP cache is only one source of useful information about who is on the network. You may consider logging into the router and check its information about connected devices; you may want to ping remote devices; perform HTTP or telnet requests to them to identify who they are.

Digital forensics is wide and relatively complex subject, I do not think you are going to deep dive into it. What you need is to configure your **network router** allowing specific devices in its network, and configure **each other device** not to become connection point to unsolicited devices.

As a side note... ensure you have proper antivirus and firewall software installed on the desktop and mobile devices!